# How can I return multiple arrays filtered from one in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation

I have some data in a MongoDb Database, and am accessing it using the NodeJS MongoDb Native Driver.

```
user: {
    _id: ****Example Id****
    name: 'Foo bar',
    examScores: [
        { subject: 'Geography', score: 80, teacher: 'Mr Foo', date: 'somedate'},
        { subject: 'History', score: 57, teacher: 'Mrs Bar', date: 'somedate'},
        { subject: 'Maths', score: 43, teacher: 'Mrs Fizz', date: 'somedate'},
        { subject: 'Geography', score: 43, teacher: 'Mr Buzz', date: 'somedate'},
        { subject: 'Geography', score: 78, teacher: 'Mr Foo', date: 'somedate'},
        { subject: 'History', score: 41, teacher: 'Mr Buzz', date: 'somedate'}
    ]
}
```

I'd like to retrieve the top ten scores/exams per subject. I haven't included more than ten exam attempts in the example for brevity.

Something like:

```
user: {
    _id: ****Example Id****
    name: 'Foo bar',
    grades: [
        { subject: 'Geography', exams: [ 
            { score: 80, teacher: 'Mr Foo', date: 'somedate' },
            { score: 78, teacher: 'Mr Foo', date: 'somedate' },
            { score: 43, teacher: 'Mr Buzz', date: 'somedate' }
            ]
        },
        { subject: 'History', exams: [
            { score: 57, teacher: 'Mrs Bar', date: 'somedate' },
            { score: 41, teacher: 'Mr Buzz', date: 'somedate'}
            ]
        },
        { subject: 'Maths', exams: [
            { score: 43, teacher: 'Mrs Fizz', date: 'somedate'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query Hope it helps. I have used [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) ,and then aggregating the data .

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$examScores"}, 

{$group:{"_id":"$examScores.subject",name: { $first: "$name" }, exams: { 

$addToSet:{ teacher: '$examScores.teacher' 

,score:'$examScores.score',date:'$examScores.date' } }}},

{$group:{"_id":null,name: { $first: "$name" }, "grades":{$push: 

{"subject":"$_id", "exams":"$exams"}}}},

{$project:{"_id":0,"grades":1,"name":1}} ])
```

the expected output I am getting is on my local machine

```
{
  "name": "Foo bar",
  "grades": [
    {
      "subject": "History",
      "exams": [
        {
          "teacher": "Mr Buzz",
          "score": 41,
          "date": "somedate"
        },
        {
          "teacher": "Mrs Bar",
          "score": 57,
          "date": "somedate"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subject": "Maths",
      "exams": [
        {
          "teacher": "Mrs Fizz",
          "score": 43,
          "date": "somedate"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subject": "Geography",
      "exams": [
        {
          "teacher": "Mr Foo",
          "score": 78,
          "date": "somedate"
        },
        {
          "teacher": "Mr Buzz",
          "score": 43,
          "date": "somedate"
        },
        {
          "teacher": "Mr Foo",
          "score": 80,
          "date": "somedate"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query :

1. Unwind the examScores array
2. Sort collection based on subject and scores in descending order since 
   you need the results for every subject in descending order of scores.
3. Group results based on the subject
4. Since you need only top 10 highest scores to be listed for every subject 
   you can use [$Slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) operation to limit to first 10 highest scores 
   for every subject.

   ```
   db.collection.aggregate([ 

                  { $unwind : "$examScores" },
                  { $sort : 
                          { "examScores.subject" : 1, 
                            "examScores.score" : -1
                          }
                  }, 
                  { $group : { 
                             "_id" : "$examScores.subject",
                             "name" : { $first: "$name" }, 
                             "examsAll" : { 
                                    $addToSet : { 
                                           teacher: '$examScores.teacher',
                                           score : '$examScores.score',
                                           date : '$examScores.date' 
                                                } 
                                          }
                               }
                  },
                  { $project : { 
                                "_id" : 1, 
                                "name" : 1, 
                                "exams" : { $slice: [ "$examsAll", 10 ] } 
                               }
                  },
                  { $group : { "_id" : null, 
                               "name" :  { $first: "$name" }, 
                               "grades" : { $push: 
                                                { "subject" : "$_id", 
                                                  "exams" : "$exams" 
                                                }
                                          }
                              }
                  },
                  { $project : { "_id" : 0,
                                 "grades" : 1,
                                 "name" : 1
                               }
                  } 
        ]);
   ```